# How to map Firebase array to Kotlin list?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I want to map array from Firebase as a list of string in Kotlin

[image]

I have been searching for answer in may threads but they doesn't answer my question

Now I fetch whole collection and I get DocumentSnapshot. When I do

```
  list = it["myArray"].toString()
```

I get string:

```
list = [text1, text2, text3]
```

How Can I convert it to list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split() like,

```
val newList = list.split(',')
```

It will split the strings from every occurrence of ',' in it, and will return a list containing all the spliced strings.

Comment: Don't forget to remove brackets and whitespaces.

fun String.removeBrackets(): String {
    return this
        .replace("[", "")
        .replace("]", "")
        .trim()
}